# What does "styled themselves of his connection" mean?

Tags: meaning

> But when those of the inhabitants who styled themselves of his connection became acquainted with him.
>
> *The Distracted Preacher*, Thomas Hardy

What does the term "styled themselves of his connection" mean?

Answer (score 1):

"Those of the inhabitants who called themselves members of the branch of the Methodist church to which he belonged."

Oxford Languages gives, as one of the definitions of *connection:*

*HISTORICAL*

*an association of Methodist Churches.*

*"the primitive Methodists broke with the Wesleyan connection in 1810"*